# How to write into internal storage of android

Tags: android, qt, qmake

I'm using qtcreator and have created an AndroidManifest.xml via my IDE which has **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission but I cannot write any file into my mobile phone storage ( /storage/self/primary or /storage/emulated/0/ ) (  error : file is not open )

something like telegram folder of Telegram application

How can I write file into this location which is visible for other users

## Updated

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="org.qtproject.example" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_NAME%% --" android:versionCode="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_CODE%% --" android:installLocation="auto">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>

        <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
                 Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->
        <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->

        <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default features based on the dependencies of the application.
                 Remove the comment if you do not require these default features. -->
        <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->

        <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
            <!-- Application arguments -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="arg1 arg2 arg3"/ -->
            <!-- Application arguments -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
            <!-- Used to specify custom system library path to run with local system libs -->
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="android.app.system_libs_prefix" android:value="/system/lib/"/> -->
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/unsupported_android_version" android:name="android.app.unsupported_android_version"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!-- Orientation-specific (portrait/landscape) data is checked first. If not available for current orientation,
                                 then android.app.splash_screen_drawable. For best results, use together with splash_screen_sticky and
                                 use hideSplashScreen() with a fade-out animation from Qt Android Extras to hide the splash screen when you
                                 are done populating your window with content. -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_portrait" android:resource="@drawable/logo_portrait" / -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_landscape" android:resource="@drawable/logo_landscape" / -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/ -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/ -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                                                    application still try to draw after
                                                    "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                                                    signal is sent! -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.auto_screen_scale_factor" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->
            <!-- extract android style -->
            <!-- available android:values :
                                * default - In most cases this will be the same as "full", but it can also be something else if needed, e.g., for compatibility reasons
                                * full - useful QWidget & Quick Controls 1 apps
                                * minimal - useful for Quick Controls 2 apps, it is much faster than "full"
                                * none - useful for apps that don't use any of the above Qt modules
                                -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
            <!-- extract android style -->
        </activity>
        <!-- For adding service(s) please check: https://wiki.qt.io/AndroidServices -->
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


</manifest>
```

Comment: please share your manifeist file and make sure you check run time storage permission.

Comment: Tell which Android version runs on used device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You probably have your function to write to the storage, You're most likely missing to check the storage permission during runtime, as @Ak23 pointed it out. Here is an example code of how You could go about chcecking and granting permission:

```
bool uploadToStorage()
{
    auto result = QtAndroid::checkPermission(QString("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"));

    if (result == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied) {
        QtAndroid::PermissionResultMap resultHash = QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync(QStringList({"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}));

        if (resultHash["android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
            return false;

        else {
            /* Here is Your method to upload to storage */

            return true;
        }
    }

    else {
        /* Here is Your method to upload to storage */

        return true;
    }
}
```

As You can see - first You check if the permission is *granted* with the `checkPermission()`, next if it is not granted You have to ask for it with the `requestPermissionsSync()` - it should show a popup with a question if You want to grant the permission to write to the storage. After ensuring that the permissions are OK, You can call the function with which You upload your files.